# php artisan queue:work gets stuck while processing a job in redis queue

Tags: laravel, redis

I set up all the config keys to use redis. It's working fine, I tested it.
Using below snippet .

```
Route::get('/counter',function() {
          $counter = Redis::incr('counter');
          return $counter;
    });

Route::get('/gename',function() {
         $redis = Redis::connection();
         $redis->set("name","John Doe");
         return $redis->get("name");
    });
```

I get the expected result.
I can also see the set keys using `KEYS '*'` in redis-cli.
Now I am using Laravel queue to dispatch the mail job to queue.

```
{
    public function sendEmail()
    {
    $emailJob = (new SendEmailJob())->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3));
    dispatch($emailJob);
    echo "email sent";
    }   
}
```

If I am not wrong, as the queue_connection is redis, It should set some keys for the job. But I don't see any set keys in redis-cli.
Also it gets stuck when I run any queue command.
 `php artisan queue:listen` OR 
`php artisan queue:work`

**.env**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:QBkErBPtVTE9UxdJXNeqlOqm6zrX7qslG5E8d/Yhmtc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=queue
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=my_username_I_won't_show_go_get_yours_it's_free
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_password_I_won't_show_go_get_yours_it's_free
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

**config/queue.php**

```
<?php

return [



    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'redis'),


    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

        'beanstalkd' => [
            'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => 0,
        ],

        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'your-queue-name'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],

    ],



    'failed' => [
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],

];
```

Comment: can you post .env file and config > queue.php data

Comment: @somsgod I added content from both the files.

Comment: Have you run these commands `php artisan queue:table` `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Well, I see the keys now. I just used `select 1` and thek `keys *` I can see two keys.
```1) "laravel_database_queues:default:delayed"
2) "laravel_database_laravel_cache:zlAVyEV2reIEYAHCLYNU1ZQv8bWhuM2xn4hDIcWE"``` But why it doesn't process when I do `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: @somsgod I am using redis, I think I don't need to run any of these commands as long as I don't want to track failed jobs.

Comment: These command are for db based queues if you want to move.